# DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead

Tags: webpack

Добавил в конфиг плагин webpack.DefinePlugin, но возникает ошибка

(node:24204) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
TypeError: dep.getResourceIdentifier is not a function
    at addDependency (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:665:30)
    at iterationOfArrayCallback (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:186:3)
    at addDependenciesBlock (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:687:5)
    at Compilation.processModuleDependencies (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:698:4)
    at afterBuild (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:978:13)
    at buildModule.err (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1006:8)
    at callback (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:611:5)
    at module.build.error (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:651:12)
    at handleParseResult (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:441:12)
    at doBuild.err (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:463:6)
    at runLoaders (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:327:12)
    at C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:370:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:211:10)
    at Array. (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:4)
    at Storage.finished (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:43:16)
    at provider (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:79:9)
    at C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')


module.exports = {

    context: path.resolve(__dirname , 'src'), // корень контекст

    // Точки входа
    entry:{
        home: './init',
        //profile: './Profile',
        //shop: './Shop',
    },

    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname , 'dist')

    },
    plugins:[
       // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            VERSION: '0.0.2',
            PRODUCTION: false,
            HTML5_SUPPORT: true
        })
    ],

    watch: false, // слежение за обновлениями
    devtool: 'source-map' // eval source-map
}
```

---

Вот файл package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-test-10",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: какая версия webpack?

Comment: Версия webpack 4.17.1

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, ваш `package.json`, вы используете yarn или npm?

Comment: Не использую, только webpack.config.js и запускаю в консоли webpack.

Comment: ну как не используете, зависимости вы через что устанавливаете?

Comment: package.json
 добавил. 
А так создал папку и сделал там npm init.

Comment: это очень плохая практика работать с вебпаком глобально, так как может быть конфликт версий, устанавливайте его локально в директории с проектом (`npm i --save-dev webpack webpack-cli`), issue с такой ошибкой уже есть на гитхабе, тимлид вебпака Тобиас говорит - цитирую `Check if webpack is installed multiple times`

Comment: Ок, спасибо. Обнаружил что выше уже была папка node modules. Когда переместил проект в корень диска, то проблемы исчезли.